# Drawing solid object by Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner for `tikz` picture. I just can use it to draw some simple diagram, but I now want to draw two pictures as below for my project. I do not know how to use `tikz` to draw such complicated figure.
[image]
[image]

This is what I tried so far to draw a tetrahedron

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
\coordinate [label=right:A] (A) at (2,0,0*\factor);
\coordinate [label=left:B] (B) at (0,0,0*\factor);
\coordinate [label=above:C] (C) at (0,2,0*\factor);
\coordinate [label=below:D] (D) at (0,0,2*\factor);

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[below left] {$z$};
\foreach \i in {A,B,C,D}
    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(\i);
\draw[-, fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (A)--(D)--(B)--cycle;
\draw[-, fill=green!30, opacity=.5] (A) --(D)--(C)--cycle;
\draw[-, fill=purple!30, opacity=.5] (B)--(D)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone give me some ideas, or better a sample of `LaTeX` code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Perhaps you should show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just added what I tried to do.

Comment: This is really too much for one question. Can you break it down and ask about the specific steps you are stuck on? Have you considered using software which knows about 3D? Also, please try to post compilable code as it is much easier to work with a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need further help, ask new questions about the specific problems you run into. There is too much here for a single question and answer. As a starting point, I transform your existing diagram into a form based on `tikz-3dplot`, which does some of the calculations automatically. This simplifies the code and makes it easier to add the second diagram in the lower sequence.

Note that Ti*k*Z is not a good choice for 3D as it does not know anything about 3D. In simple cases, you can fake things successfully, but for more complicated diagrams, it will be much easier to use software which knows about 3D.

In particular, to draw in 3D, you have to do the calculations. `tikz-3dplot` automates some of this, but you still have to think about the translation from 3D to 2D. In particular, you need to draw things further away first if they overlap at all with things nearer to you. In this case, you need to draw and fill the sides of the solids in an appropriate order if you want to get a reasonable result.

[image: two stages of second sequence]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, >=Latex]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity=.5, draw opacity=.5, text opacity=1]
    \draw [fill=blue!50!cyan] (2,0,0) coordinate [label=left:D] (D) -- (0,0,2) coordinate [label=above right:C] (C) -- (0,0,0) coordinate [label={[xshift=-10pt]above left:B}] (B) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=magenta] (B) -- (C) -- (0,2,0) coordinate [label=above right:A] (A) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=yellow] (D) -- (C) -- (A) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=45mm]
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=.5, draw opacity=.5, text opacity=1]
      \draw [fill=blue!50!cyan] (0,0,0) coordinate [label={[anchor=north west,xshift=-5pt]below:$E_0$}] (E0) -- (0,0,2) coordinate [label=above right:$E_0'$] (E0') -- (0,2,2) coordinate [label={right:$E_2'$}] (E2') -- (0,2,0) coordinate [label=above right:$E_2$] (E2) -- cycle;
      \draw [fill=purple] (E0) -- (E0') -- (2,0,2) coordinate [label=left:$E_1'$] (E1') -- (2,0,0) coordinate [label=left:$E_1$] (E1) -- cycle;
      \draw [fill=green!50!cyan] (E0) -- (E2) -- (E1) -- cycle;
      \draw [densely dashed] (E1') -- (E0) -- (E2');
      \draw [fill=yellow] (E1) -- (E2) -- (E2') -- (E1') -- cycle;
      \draw [fill=magenta] (E1') -- (E2') -- (E0') -- cycle;
      \draw [densely dashed] (E1) -- (E2');
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \draw [->, shorten >=5mm, shorten <=5mm] ($(C)!.5!(A)$) [bend left] to node [midway, above] {$G_{i,2}$} ($(E1')!.5!(E0')$) ;
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Curves are trickier, but are covered in `tikz-3dplot`'s manual, so I would suggest starting from a suitable example there.

Comment: Thank you so much I am trying to the remaining of your work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need 3d graphics for this simple drawing; it can be mimicked in 2d.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\newcommand\blobA[3][]%
  {\draw (#3) coordinate (#2-1)
     to [out=-90,in=-180] ++(0.5,-0.3) coordinate (#2-2)
     to [out=0,in=-180] ++(1.0,0.1) coordinate (#2-3)
     to [out=0,in=-180] ++(0.3,-0.1) coordinate (#2-4)
     to [out=0,in=-90] ++(0.2,0.2) coordinate (#2-5);
   \draw[#1] (#2-5)
     to [out=90,in=0] ++(-1,0.5)  coordinate (#2-6)
     to [out=180,in=90] (#2-1);
   \node[shape=ellipse,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.3cm,outer sep=2pt] 
     (#2) at ($0.5*(#2-1)+0.5*(#2-5)+(0,0.05)$) {};  
  }
\newcommand\blobB[3][]%
  {\draw (#3) coordinate (#2-1)
     to [out=-90,in=135] ++(0.2,-0.4)
     to [out=-45,in=-135] ++(0.5,0.1)
     to [out=45,in=-90] ++(0.4,1.4)
     to [out=90,in=-45] ++(-0.2,0.4)
     to [out=135,in=45] ++(-1,0) coordinate(#2-2)
     to [out=-135,in=90] ++(0.2,-0.9)
     to [out=-90,in=90] (#2-1);
   \node[shape=ellipse,minimum width=1.8cm,minimum height=3.3cm,outer sep=2pt] 
     (#2) at ($(#2-1)+(0.5,0.65)$) {};  
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=1.5]
\small
  \blobA{a}{0,0}
  \blobA[dashed]{b}{2.8,0}
  \blobA{c}{2.8,0.9}
  \blobB{d}{5.6,0}
  \draw (b-1) -- (c-1) (b-5) -- (c-5);
  \draw[->] (a) --node[above]{$\iota_0$} (b); 
  \draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (a) --node[above]{$\iota_1$} (c-1);
  \node at (a) {$X$};
  \node at (c) {$X\times I$};
  \node at (d) {$Y$};
  \draw[->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (a) to[bend left] node[above]{$f_1$} (d-2);
  \draw[->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (a) to[bend right] node[below]{$f_0$} (d-1);
  \draw[->,shorten <=2pt] (c-5|-d) --node[above]{$H$} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really need some code like this, because i am new to tikz. In case I need to draw something different I can imitate your work :D